# SQL Server 2008 only delete if field is unique

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I currently have this:

```
DELETE FROM t
FROM (
    SELECT 
          *
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY Street, CAST(PC AS CHAR(4)) 
                    ORDER BY CAST(PC AS CHAR(4)) 
            )
    FROM Locals where DATALENGTH(PC) < 13
) t 
WHERE rn > 1
```

but I only want to delete if the `PC` column is the same.

Comment: Please show example "before" and "after" data.

Comment: PC field is the same as what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE t
FROM (
      SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PC ORDER BY PC)
      FROM Locals 
      WHERE DATALENGTH(PC) < 13
      ) t
WHERE t.rn > 1
```

See example on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc5d4/1)

Answer (score 1):

So if the PC field is like the following: sw1 xyz, sw1 yxz, sw1 xyz. I would like to delete all the entries where the PC field has already been duplicated so in the example above it would be delete all the entries that have sw1 xyz in the PC field but keep one of them.